# Python corrupted: how do I clean a failed install or reinstall a fresh instance?

Tags: python

I was given wrong advice to install DEEPIN SOFTWARE CENTER on Ubuntu 10.04.3. I learned later that this app was not built for Ubuntu 10.x, but for 11.x.  The developer has not helped at all with any troubleshooting.The person who recommended for me to install it has also been unable to help me resolve the problem, apart from providing a generic apt-get purge < package > command, which didn't work.

Deepin Software Center initially screwed up my installation/updating procedures.  I managed to purge all instances of the Deepin Software Center, from disc, except in Python, which STILL retains information on an unable-to-be completed Deepin install, and tries valiantly every time I update a package, to complete it.

How can I purge this unfinished install information from Python ?  Alternatively, can I simply download a fresh instance of Python, & overwrite the corrupted one ?

If so, please advise on the steps necessary to do this.  I'm happy to reinstall Python, if it clears the residual problem ..

All help most gratefully appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to do the same thing, because of a similar (I belive) bug. But the reinstall process just doesn't work. Here is my question:
[Update Manager won't open (error related to pythonverbose)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206955/update-manager-wont-open-error-related-to-pythonverbose)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not providing error output, or a description in what sense python is broken, it's harder to help you.

The general way to reinstall a package is `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python`

Comment: Doesn't that cause problems, since apt-get uses python?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem. My project was using pymongo module in python2 and this pymongo internally uses the abc library. I tried lot of solution and searched a lot but none of the solution worked out.  So I planned to re-installed or remove the python completely from my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.  But sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7  command was also failing and was throwing same abc module not found error.  So I finally Did few hacks and cracks. Here are the steps -

Removing all python version manually

- sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/python2.x as well as python3.x
- sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.x as well as python3.x
- sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.x as well as python 3.x

Updating Ubuntu

- sudo apt-get update

In Between if you get this error **The package  needs to be reinstalled ubuntu** Then  Run following command

```
sudo vi /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

And delete all the lines from above file for the package above package_name

Now download a python tgz file from https://www.python.org/downloads/ and unzip it and CD into it

```
./configure
make test
sudo make install
```

Python should be installed now.  Check by running python