# Update Manager won't open (error related to pythonverbose)

Tags: python, update-manager, software-sources

I'm having an issue with update-manager. Last night, my computer restart suddenly during the update process. Now it won't open and it keep appearing on the notifier with a message warning that an error occurred. The error is the same that is displayed when I try to open it on the terminal:

```
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
EOFError: EOF read where not expected
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 26, in <module>
 from __future__ import print_function
EOFError: EOF read where not expected
```

I've already seen some questions here, but most of them are related to problems with ppas and the source.list file. This seems to be a bug on update-manager itself. I've already tried to remove it and install again, but the problem persists. I also noted another bug: my source-center doesn't open too. The message for it is similar to the other one:

```
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
EOFError: EOF read where not expected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 5, in <module>
    from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function
EOFError: EOF read where not expected
```

For now I'm using apt-get update && upgrade for updating and the Synaptic for the source management. But I really would like to fix this stuff. Anyone can help?

I'm with Ubuntu 12.10, Gnome-remix, 64-bits.

Comment: This seems to be an error on quantal. Other people had this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1055190

Comment: Other apps have the same problem: gnome-tweak-tool and apt-add-repository. It looks that pyhton3 is with serious bugs.

Comment: Here is someone with another problem related to file corruption of python. It seems that reinstall it doesn't work :( http://askubuntu.com/questions/107430/python-corrupted-how-do-i-clean-a-failed-install-or-reinstall-a-fresh-instance/

Answer (score 0):

The error message could be a symptom of Python compiled module (`.pyc` ) corruption, which is not unlikely given the unexpected sudden restart. I experience this with wajig recently.

The solution was to delete the `.pyc` file corresponding to the failing module (in your case `__future__.pyc` as far as i can tell). This `.pyc` file might be located in a `__pycache__` subfolder. You should be able to safely `sudo rm -r` this folder, it will be recreated as needed.